# Validate form with jquery-validate using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I have the following problem, I have performed a function to update my data with PHP and Codeigniter, using AJAX too .. everything works fine, but it turns out that I want to validate my form using jquery-validate before performing the AJAX request, for that already I have my validation rules and my code is as follows:

```js
function edit(id = null) {

    if (!id) {
        alert('error');
        return;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'roles/get_data_id/' + id,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            $("#edit_name").val(response.Name);
            $("#edit_description").val(response.Description);      

            $("#form_edit").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {
                var form = $(this); 

                $.ajax({
                    url: form.attr('action') + '/' + id,
                    type: 'post',
                    data: form.serialize(),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response) {
                        if(response.success === true) {
                            $("#modal_edit").modal('hide');

                            alert('The data were updated');

                            $("#form_edit")[0].reset();
                            table_data.ajax.reload(null, false);  
                        } else {
                            $("#modal_edit").modal('hide');
                            alert('Error updating data');
                        }
                    }// /succes
                }); // /ajax
                return false;  
            });       
        }
    });
}
```

The code works fine .. update my data .. now my question is where to add the following code with my validation rules:

```js
$('#form_edit').validate({
    highlight: function (input) {
        $(input).parents('.form-line').addClass('error');
    },
    unhighlight: function (input) {
        $(input).parents('.form-line').removeClass('error');
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        $(element).parents('.form-group').append(error);
    }
});
```

This is my current code:

```
function edit(id = null) {

  if (!id) {
    alert('error');
    return;
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: 'roles/get_data_id/' + id,
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      $("#edit_name").val(response.Name);
      $("#edit_description").val(response.Description);

      $('#form_edit').validate({
        highlight: function(input) {
          $(input).parents('.form-line').addClass('error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(input) {
          $(input).parents('.form-line').removeClass('error');
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
          $(element).parents('.form-group').append(error);
        },
        submitHandler: function() {

          $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action') + '/' + id,
            type: 'post',
            data: form.serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.success === true) {
                  $("#modal_edit").modal('hide');

                  alert('The data were updated');

                  $("#form_edit")[0].reset();
                  table_data.ajax.reload(null, false);
                } else {
                  $("#modal_edit").modal('hide');
                  alert('Error updating data');
                }
              } // /succes
          }); // /ajax
          return false;
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

this code my form:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="smallModalLabel">Edit rol</h4>
      </div>
      <form id="form_edit" action="<?php echo base_url();?>rol/edit" method="POST">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group form-float">
            <label class="form-label">Name</label>
            <div class="form-line">
              <input type="text" id="edit_name" name="edit_name" class="form-control" maxlength="20" minlength="5" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group form-float">
            <label class="form-label">Description</label>
            <div class="form-line">
              <textarea id="edit_description" name="edit_description" rows="3" class="form-control no-resize" required></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link waves-effect">update</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-link waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have an `.ajax()` function inside the `submitHandler` of `.validate()`, which you've put inside of another `.ajax()` function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made you a **[WORKING DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/a00ofvlPD6Q2NoQPFHry)**, 
I hope you will figure out how to continue from there.

HTML Changes:

```
<form id="form_edit">
<button id="submitForm" type="submit" class="btn btn-link waves-effect">update</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

$("#submitForm").on("click", edit);

    // introduce the validation rules to the form! 
    $('#form_edit')
        .validate({
            highlight: function(input) {
                $(input).parents('.form-line').addClass('error');
            },
            unhighlight: function(input) {
                $(input).parents('.form-line').removeClass('error');
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                $(element).parents('.form-group').append(error);
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                //Will execute only when the form passed validation.
                OnSubmit(form);
            }
        });


    function OnSubmit(form) {
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action') + '/' + id,
            type: 'post',
            data: form.serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.success === true) {
                    $("#modal_edit").modal('hide');
                    alert('The data were updated');
                    $("#form_edit")[0].reset();
                    table_data.ajax.reload(null, false);
                } else {
                    $("#modal_edit").modal('hide');
                    alert('Error updating data');
                }
            } // /success
        }); // /ajax
    }


    function edit(id = null) {

        if (!id) {
            alert('error');
            return;
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: 'roles/get_data_id/' + id,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                $("#edit_name").val(response.Name);
                $("#edit_description").val(response.Description);      

                return false;  
            }
        });       
    }

});
```

Comment: I have the following error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function. I do not know if I should write a ',' at the end of my validation rules .. before starting the OnSubmit function

Comment: I have a problem with the syntax error, it does not work, in the edit function I retrieve the data according to the id and I take them to my form in my modal window .. but now it does not take anything and I get this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: edit is Not defined

Comment: @FernandoBanegas You didn't post the call to the `edit` function , but you can try make it global.

Comment: I will put the code in my question, from my form in the modal

Comment: Copy the code of my form in the question, so that it is understood better. I'm learning to use ajax and this is driving me crazy

Comment: Try `$('button[type='submit']').on("click",window.edit())` instead of the action you have in your `Form` element.

Comment: I do not understand, should I delete the action from my form ?, and write $ ('button [type =' submit ']'. On ("click", window.edit ()), inside my script?

Comment: @FernandoBanegas I have made for you a fiddle, look at my edited answer.
It's not handling your ajax request, just validating the form, the rest you can do by your self.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time .. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Sparky there isn't.

Comment: I see it now.  Ok.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `submitHandler` provided by the jQuery validation, this way the AJAX will fire only when the validation rules are passed:

```
$('#form_edit').validate({
  highlight: function(input) {
    $(input).parents('.form-line').addClass('error');
  },
  unhighlight: function(input) {
    $(input).parents('.form-line').removeClass('error');
  },
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    $(element).parents('.form-group').append(error);
  },
  submitHandler: function() {
    //your AJAX code goes here
    edit(your_id_param_goes_here);
  }

});
```

Comment: The validation works, but it sends me to the action in a blank page, I would have to change that inside the ajax

Comment: @FernandoBanegas, ok. So there's a problem? Do you need more help?

Comment: Yes, I have placed the code you mentioned. And the validations work, but I do not update the data, apparently the action post, does not work

Comment: @FernandoBanegas you said the `AJAX` works in your question. So it should work now too.

Comment: Of course it worked, but now that adds the code, does not update, and instead of updating and displaying the alert, send me a blank page with the url of my function, I will upload the code as I have so far

Comment: @FernandoBanegas, you would just have to call the `edit` function inside the `submitHandler`.

Comment: I have updated my question, copy the current code that I have

Comment: @FernandoBanegas, you're using it all wrong. See my last comment. As I said call the `edit` function inside the `submitHandler` function.

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand how I should call my edit function inside the submitHandler

Comment: @FernandoBanegas, how did you call the function before asking the question? From where do you get the `id`? What I mean by calling the function is this `edit()` with the `id` parameter inside. See the updated answer also.

Comment: If you check the code, I get the id in the first ajax, by post, if there is a response I execute the other ajax, the action of my form has the following:
<Form id = "form_edit" action = "<? Php echo base_url ();?> Roles / edit" method = "POST">